# edit.php all post not working

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, woocommerce-offtopic, post-status

i am using publish press plugin to create a custom post status i changed the all post status into public, using this

```
register_post_status(
    $status->slug,
    [
        'label'       => $status->name,
        'public'   => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        '_builtin'    => false,
        'label_count' => _n_noop("{$status->name} <span class='count'>(%s)</span>",
            "{$status->name} <span class='count'>(%s)</span>"),
    ]
);
```

all post shown at front end but edit.php all post page not working it not showing the all the post which is relevant to custom post type and it also affected the woocommerce

Comment: Where did you put this code? Have you defined the `$status` variable you're using in it anywhere?

Comment: i just edited at publish press plugin file wp-content/plugins/publishpress/modules/custom-status/custom-status.php

Comment: @JacobPeattie all post status are now show at front end but edit.php file don't shows the all posts
eg, edit.php?post_type=shop_order it shows that  No orders found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution when i enter all the custom post status to **public** it declare the post_type to default post as global so applied filter to change the global post_type based what type request get in URL

```
function publishPress_allPost_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( is_admin() && array_key_exists( 'post_type', $_GET ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['post_type'] );
        add_filter( 'the_posts', 'publishPress_allPost_the_posts', 10, 2 );
    }
}

function publishPress_allPost_the_posts( $posts, &$wp_query )
{
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $GLOBALS['post_type'] );
    return $posts;
}
```